# Converting standard deviation of a score to standard deviation of a percent?

Tags: statistics, variance

I have the standard deviation for scores on a test that is out of 105; it is 1.9. If I want to convert scores to percents, I do: score * 100/105. But how do I do the same with standard deviation? Can I also do: std dev * 100/105?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how standard deviation scales.  By the way, $1.9$ is an awfully low standard deviation for a test out of $105$.

Comment: Thank you! The low standard deviation was due to a small sample size of high-scoring participants :)